# Adding a background image to UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `UIScrollView` added to a UIView. Now i have added a background image to the scrollVIew.

The image has a fixed size like 320X460. But when the scroll view scrolls further down i can see white colour areas on the scroll view.

How could i prevent this ?

I tried adding the image to the view, and making the scrollview background as clearColor, but it doesn't work.

```
[scrollView addSubView:imageView];

self.view = scrollview;

[scrollview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: you need to add the imageview to the uiview that holds the scrollview, not to the scrollview.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try setting a tileable image as your background color.

```
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tileableImage.png"]];
```

Comment: But the problem here is that when you change the device orientation to landscape the image is repeated until it fills all of the screen...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to tile an image, insert the image view:

```
[webView insertSubview:backgroundImage atIndex:0];
```

Then set it's size to match the webView at creation or in viewWillLayoutSubviews.